# Is it possible to set a page title with header?

Tags: php, html

I have a main page (index.php) and if the client is not logged in, it redirect to the login.php.

```
header("Location: login.php");
```

The problem is that the search engines display as name the "example.com" instead of the title of the index or the login.

I am thinking if it is possible to do something like that.

```
header("Title: Example");
header("Location: login.php");
```

Comment: [You shouldn't ask how to set a title with header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should ask "why search engines display as name the "example.com" instead of the title of the index" and **provide the relevant information**.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me as though you want the Search Engine to index (and pick up the title) of your login page only - not the redirecting one, so set an HTTP status code in your redirect to inform them of the correct status of those pages.

I'd suggest using 302 (Found) - this will indicate to the Search Engines that - while the page exists - it's redirecting them (and non-logged in users) to another page - which is the one of interest.

Something like this:

```
header("Location: https://www.example.com/login.php", true, 302);
```

Then on your login page just set up the HTML correctly as you would otherwise including:

```
<head><title>Your Page Title</title></head>
```

Now search engines will not index the redirected page, but only the login page with your correctly set title.

Comment: Ok I have added the ```, true, 302``` to my code. Now I have to wait for the bots. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the title of a HTML document by using the `<title>` element inside the `<head>` element. You cannot do it via a HTTP response header.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example title</title>
  </head>
  <body>Some content</body>
</html>
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title

Comment: Cannot modify header information.

Comment: What do you mean? Be more specific please. It's your site, so I would assume you can set whatever titles you want on your pages? Why is that a problem?